# list table using hostname and port number

Tags: php, mysql

I need to list the table from known database 'dbname' from the host name and port number.

> mysql_connect(): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

I tried with code

```
$dbname = 'inh_db';
$port = '3386';
if (!mysql_connect('182.35.5.00', 'name', 'dbname')) {
echo 'Could not connect to mysql';
exit;
}

$sql = "SHOW TABLES FROM $dbname";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
  echo "Table: {$row[0]}\n";
}
mysql_free_result($result);
```

Comment: login credentials, probably ip or port are wrong, so it can't connect at all. Also please don't use `mysql_connect()`, it's deprecated and removed in PHP 7. Have a look at Mysqli or PDO. If the database is on the same server as the PHP script, use 127.0.0.1 as the address rather than the server's IP. Sql only accepts connections from localhost by default, you need to permit other hosts to access it before it will work.

Answer (score 0):

mysql_connect('182.35.5.0:3386', 'name', 'password', 'dbname')

details:

http://php.net/manual/zh/function.mysql-connect.php